# how do i decide technology stack for my platform?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, backend

Please help me out i am willing to create a platform for online education guide.i want a mobile application as well as web app both should use same data and backend i have decided to go for **react native** to develop mobile app and **react** for web i am confused about backend. in future i want to stream videos on my platform also Q/A section,comments,chats etc. what will be the suitable technology stack for my platform mainly what combination of **database** + **framework** should i use.

Comment: for back end you can use graphql with relay modern and also database as a mongodb or sql if you want accurate work then go with sql

Answer (score 0):

Chose your database tool for React Native Application  - [Read Here](https://www.simform.com/react-native-database-selection-guide/)

Chose your Back End framework for React Native Application - [Read Here](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactnative/comments/94fx3i/best_framework_backend_to_use_with_react_native/)

**Note:**

Since React/ReactNative both are JS Based you can simply use [Node JS](https://nodejs.org/en/) as back end framework and [MongoDb](https://www.mongodb.com/) as database tool simply.